# Detecting and Removing Commas from only a portion of a string in a large list of strings (R)

Tags: regex, r, string

I have a large list of strings where each item on the list shows like this:

```
largeList<-
  c("\t\t\t73,Tuesday,08/23/2014,09:03PM,Data Transfer,KB,\"60 KB\",MSDG,AT,GPRR,,0.00",
    "\t\t\t74,Tuesday,08/23/2014,10:17PM,Data Transfer,KB,\"1,412 KB\",MSDG,AT,GPRR,,0.00",       
    "\t\t\t75,Wednesday,08/24/2014,12:08AM,Data Transfer,KB,\"2,589 KB\",MSDG,AT,GPRR,,0.00",          
    "\t\t\t76,Wednesday,08/24/2014,12:26PM,Data Transfer,KB,\"23,576 KB\",MSDG,AT,GPRR,,0.00",
    "\t\t\t85,Thursday,08/25/2014,05:17PM,Data Transfer,KB,\"78,088 KB\",MSDG,AT,GPRR,,0.00")
```

I am trying to split the data by commas using

```
lapply(largeList, "strsplit",",")
```

but the issue I am coming across is that while most of the values are less than 1000 (like "\"60 KB\"), there are large values have a comma in them every once in a while (like "23,576 KB\"). I have tried

```
grep('(["KB"])', test, value=TRUE)
```

to try and find the pattern for that only but all that keeps happening is that the whole string is returned. I know that eventually I would use gsub() to replace only that portion but I am at a loss as to what the pattern should be. The best partial solution I was able to come up with is using the stringr package:

```
str_locate_all(test, '([""])')
```

which returns with

```
[[1]]
     start end
[1,]    52  52
[2,]    62  62
```

on the 5th value of the example list above:

```
     [5] "\t\t\t85,Thursday,08/25/2014,05:17PM,Data Transfer,KB,\"78,088 KB\",MSDG,AT,GPRR,,0.00"
```

And as I understand this does target the start and end of the portion I want to change. But I feel like there is a better way to manipulate the string, I just can't seem to figure out the regular expression for it. Anyone have a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: Perhaps: `lapply(largeList,strsplit,split="(?<![0-9]),(?![0-9])",perl=T)`

Comment: Try `gsub(".*?\"([^\"]+).*", "\\1", largeList)`.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Is it only the size of the transfer/file (i.e., the number preceding KB? Or is it a split of the string that ignores the commas in numbers?

Comment: BTW, welcome to SO and that is a nice start.

Comment: Maybe use find instead of split (if R supports these constructs) `(?:(?:^|,|\r?\n)\s*)(?:"([^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*)"(?:\s*(?:(?=,|\r?\n)|$))|([^,]*)(?:\s*(?:(?=,)|$)))`

Comment: @MichaelChirico, What I am looking for is actually to split the string that ignores the commas in the numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps save yourself an afternoon of head-banging regular expressions and consider `read.csv()`. Since the KB values you are looking for are surrounded by quotation marks in your data, and you want to split the rest of the data on the comma anyway, this seems like a nice choice.  Notice column `V7` in the following.

```
read.csv(text = largeList, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#   V1        V2         V3      V4            V5 V6        V7   V8 V9  V10 V11 V12
# 1 73   Tuesday 08/23/2014 09:03PM Data Transfer KB     60 KB MSDG AT GPRR  NA   0
# 2 74   Tuesday 08/23/2014 10:17PM Data Transfer KB  1,412 KB MSDG AT GPRR  NA   0
# 3 75 Wednesday 08/24/2014 12:08AM Data Transfer KB  2,589 KB MSDG AT GPRR  NA   0
# 4 76 Wednesday 08/24/2014 12:26PM Data Transfer KB 23,576 KB MSDG AT GPRR  NA   0
# 5 85  Thursday 08/25/2014 05:17PM Data Transfer KB 78,088 KB MSDG AT GPRR  NA   0
```

To deliver only the KB values you can use

```
read.csv(text = largeList, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[[7]]
# [1] "60 KB"     "1,412 KB"  "2,589 KB"  "23,576 KB" "78,088 KB"
```

Additionally, if you need to retain the exact text like `0.00` and `\t` in the split data, you can add the argument `colClasses = "character"` and remove `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.  This way the data will look exactly as it did, only split on the relevant commas.

```
read.csv(text = largeList, header = FALSE, colClasses = "character")
#         V1        V2         V3      V4            V5 V6        V7   V8 V9  V10 V11  V12
# 1 \t\t\t73   Tuesday 08/23/2014 09:03PM Data Transfer KB     60 KB MSDG AT GPRR     0.00
# 2 \t\t\t74   Tuesday 08/23/2014 10:17PM Data Transfer KB  1,412 KB MSDG AT GPRR     0.00
# 3 \t\t\t75 Wednesday 08/24/2014 12:08AM Data Transfer KB  2,589 KB MSDG AT GPRR     0.00
# 4 \t\t\t76 Wednesday 08/24/2014 12:26PM Data Transfer KB 23,576 KB MSDG AT GPRR     0.00
# 5 \t\t\t85  Thursday 08/25/2014 05:17PM Data Transfer KB 78,088 KB MSDG AT GPRR     0.00
read.csv(text = largeList, header = FALSE, colClasses = "character")[[7]]
# [1] "60 KB"     "1,412 KB"  "2,589 KB"  "23,576 KB" "78,088 KB"
```

Comment: Nice redirection of the question to solve it more efficiently.

Comment: Wow this actually does exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @Tai0827 - I figured it was close.  Np, happy to help out.

Answer (score 1):

To get all the values inside double quotes, use

```
gsub("^[^\"]*\"([^\"]+).*", "\\1", largeList)
```

The pattern matches 0 or more characters other than `"` from the start of the string up to the first `"`, then captures the contents inside the double quotes, and matches the rest of the contents. Then the captured text replaces the whole match.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/S5p5dQ)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try:
gsub('.*\"(.*)\".*','\\1',largeList)
[1] "60 KB"     "1,412 KB"  "2,589 KB"  "23,576 KB" "78,088 KB"
```